# Porto Theme - Category View - "Add to Cart" change to view product

Tags: list.phtml, category-view, porto-theme, porto

i know this question has been asked on other posts but i believe Porto theme uses different files/layouts.

I'm trying to change the "add to cart/basket" button to "View" and take you to the product page in my Porto theme.
i have read on other stack posts to change list.phtml however the code people refer to are not in Porto Theme.

our page is https://www.redbanduk.co.uk/construction-groundwork/hand-held-cutters/husqvarna-disc-cutters/petrol

i'm hoping someone is able to help as this is driving me mad.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not best practice but I just used translate line and change it from "Add to basket" to "buy now" as a client wanted it that way.

Might be a work around for now

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i did play with this option and yes it works but still adds items to the cart rather than redirects to the product page.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it may be wise to share the form section of my list.phtml.

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                        <?php if(isset($_category_config['qty_field']) && $_category_config['qty_field']):?>
                                            <div class="qty-box">
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qtyminus"><i class="porto-icon-minus"></i></a>
                                                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"/>
                                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qtyplus"><i class="porto-icon-plus"></i></a>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif;?>
                                        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                        <button type="submit"
                                                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                class="action tocart primary">
                                            <span><?php echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
```